# WPF Transparent UserControl Background

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Well, i saw this question so many times, but all the answers given to TS are not applicable to my UserControl. =(

The problem is, when i use Background property on UserControl inside Designer, it works only if i set it to real color, like Red, Blue, Green, etc.

However, when i try to set it to Transparent, it again becomes white.

I have a window which looks like this
[image]

What im trying to achieve, is this
[image]

But all im getting is this  (this whiteish background, or really any color except transparent)
[image]

Any suggestions on how to make it possible?

P.S. This custom user control is a kind of a MessageBox

**Update! Forgot to mention source code for this control**
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/563144/WPF-Dialog-MessageBox-Manager (by **[Ronald Schlenker](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/RonaldSchlenker)**)

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string languageCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        string Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        TimedCall();
    }

    private void TimedCall()
    {
        System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer((obj) =>
        {
            ShowMessageBox();
            timer.Dispose();
        },
                    null, 3000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        var _dialogManager = new DialogManager(this, Dispatcher);
        _dialogManager
        .CreateMessageDialog("Test", "I'm a dialogafsaffsfsf", DialogMode.Ok)
        .Show();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that makes the messagebox shown?

Comment: @tagaPdyk sorry, forgot to mention link for code, its in main thread post now

Comment: Nope. Your code. Looking at the link, how am I supposed to check the problem? But the looks of it, you are calling the messagebox inside the constructor of your Window. That may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Loaded event on your Window and call TimedCall() there. Your window is not loaded yet, that is why the background you desire is not taking in effect yet.

Comment: gosh, thank you so much, i totally forgot about Loaded event, havent coded in C# for a really long time